# The installation of libc6:amd64 on the Jetson Nano / Arm64 removes every ARM64 package on the system

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, virtualization, arm

I'm trying to build / Run Android Cuttlefish on PC / jetson nano - ARM64 (running ubuntu 18.04) following this tutorial : [How to Build/Run Cuttlefish on PC/ARM64](https://sites.google.com/junsun.net/how-to-run-cuttlefish/home)

at some point ,I should do :

**[on ARM64]**

**Setup to run x86_64 binaries**

**Do following as root user:**

```
apt install qemu-user-static

dpkg --add-architecture amd64
```

remove the ubuntu sources and add these sources on /etc/apt/source.list :

> deb [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic
> main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
> bionic main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
> bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
> bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
> bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src [arch=arm64,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
> bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
> restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports
> main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security
> main restricted universe multiverse

```
apt update

apt install libc6:amd64
```

the consequence of this approach is that ubuntu removes all the arm64 packages already installed on the system and it becomes totally broken. How can I avoid this ?

**Update 1 : Someone told me : "One tricky thing about how dpkg's multi-arch works is that to install a library for several architectures, the versions of the packages for all architectures have to be exactly the same. So if for some reason the version of the libc6:arm64 package that is currently installed on your system is not exactly the same as the version of the libc6:amd64 package that you're telling it to install, apt might propose to solve that by removing libc6:arm64. And since almost everything depends on libc, that would make it necessary to remove a large number of packages. To determine whether that really is the cause of the problem, you should find out which versions of libc6 are available/installed for the two architectures.What matters is not the high-level version of the source, but the exact versions of the binary packages. If you had e.g. version 2.27-3ubuntu1 of libc6 for arm64 but version 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 of libc6 for amd64, then you can't install both at the same time. Even though both of them come from the same upstream source"**

I have determined that after the upgrade ubuntu 18.04 uses :

**libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_arm64.deb ; libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4).**

I've downloaded but not installed libc6:amd64 with the command :

```
apt-get download libc6:amd64
```

and I saw that its version is : **libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb....**

**UPDATE 2 : this commands sequence don't work :**

```
gedit sources.list
apt update
apt install qemu-user-static
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
apd update
apt install libc6:amd64

some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: libgtk-3-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-atk-1.0 (>= 2.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-freedesktop (>= 1.39.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.40.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:amd64 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
 libc6:amd64 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libcairo2 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-common (>= 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 2.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcolord2 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcups2 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libepoxy0 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.30.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 0.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.40.5) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: librest-0.7-0 (>= 0.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.9.91) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (>= 1.9.91) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-egl1 (>= 1.15.0)
              Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxcursor1 (> 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxinerama1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxkbcommon0 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: adwaita-icon-theme
              Recommends: libgtk-3-bin
 libpango-1.0-0 : Depends: fontconfig (>= 2.1.91)
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.1) but it is not going to be installed
 lxlock : Depends: light-locker but it is not going to be installed or
                   xscreensaver but it is not going to be installed or
                   gnome-screensaver but it is not going to be installed or
                   i3lock but it is not going to be installed or
                   suckless-tools but it is not going to be installed or
                   slim but it is not going to be installed
 python : Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib  2.7.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**libc6 : Breaks: libc6:amd64 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
libc6:amd64 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed**

**UPDATE 3: this seems to be the solution :**

```
-) gedit sources.list
-) apt update
-) apt install qemu-user-static 
-) dpkg --add-architecture amd64
-) apt update
-) dpkg -i --force-all libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
-) apt install libc6:arm64
-) apt --fix-broken install
-) apt install libc6:amd64
-) apt update
-) apt upgrade
```

**It says : the following packages have been kept back :
libc-dev-bin ; libc6 ; libc6-dbg ; libc6-dev**

Comment: Jetson is ARM, not x86_64. So it is absolutely expected.